# SOA and web applications

Tags: php, asp.net, html, web, soa

I am confused, I only know SOA is a philosophical paradigm, like OOP
I used to have a hard time to really understand what is OOP. Now I guess it is time for SOA too. Could you provide me a simple concrete practical example of a SOA application ?

Answer (score 3):

Service Oriented Architecture is a paradigm often used in enterprises. The idea is to create reusable service components (often interfaces exposing functionality in existing systems/applications). There are tons of resources on the web that can be used as starting points on when and how to use SOA in various scenarios.

It is not really applicable to use SOA when building a single application. A standard architecture for a single application is usually the N-layered approach (e.g. UI, business, service, data). If you are building a new application and want to prepare it for use in a SOA environment, you could follow a few guidelines such as exposing the application functionality as services (SOAP over HTTP is popular but not required), thinking about the various information entities that the application handles and whether or not to expose operations on these, and lastly but most importantly contact enterprise architects to identify the functionality of the application that is most likely to be reused, and define how a future, reusable, service would look like and requirements on the same.